# compute relative percentage pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to compute the relative percentage of each category using pandas, I know I need to use groupby using pandas but I am kinda lost.

Input:

```
ID | stringValue | FloatValue
A  | 'string'    | 2
A  | 'string2'   | 8
B  | 'string'    | 5
```

Expected Output:

```
ID | stringValue | FloatValue | Perc
A  | 'string'    | 2          | 20   
A  | 'string2'   | 8          | 80
B  | 'string'    | 5          | 100
```

The expected output groups value by their ID and calculate the percrentage.
Here, in A you have two value `2` and `8`. So the percentage should be `100 * 2 / (2+8)` and `100 * 8 / (2+8)`. For the id B, there is only one value so the Perc should be 100

Comment: sorry I don't understand how this output appeared, why is 5 resulting in 100%?

Comment: Yeha Sorry, I rephrased my question

Comment: so did you mean how can you make  a new column multiplied or divided by 10? I answered that, but I am guessing I misunderstood

Comment: I definitely mischosen my values, I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try:

```
df['Perc'] = df.groupby('ID')['FloatValue'].transform(lambda x: (x/x.sum()) * 100)

# Output


   ID   stringValue FloatValue  Perc
0   A   'string'      2         20
1   A   'string2'     8         80
2   B   'string'      5        100
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data is a pandas DataFrame named "data", the following code should do the trick:

```
data["Perc"] = data.apply(lambda x: x["FloatValue"] * 100 / data.groupby(["ID"]).sum()["FloatValue"][x["ID"]], axis=1)
```

It groups your items by ID and compute the total sum of FloatValue. The apply method of DataFrame then create a new Series by dividing the FloatValue by the corresponding group sum.

Answer (score 0):

If the 5 -> 100% is a typo and you literally just mean how can I make my number look like a percentage, you can do that easily.

If you want it to be % literally then you will have to divide by 10, and you can print it by multiplying by 100.

If you want it to be a percentage and you will keep that in mind, then do the opposite and multiply by 10.

You can do this by simply doing:

```
df["Perc"] = df["FloatValue"] * 10
```